# Automatically insert class name

Tags: eclipse, templates

Is it possible to type template for Eclipse to automatically insert class name during coding?

For example i need to insert in many classes:

```
private static final String LOG_CATEGORY_TYPE = [CURRENT_CLASS_NAME].class.getName();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Window > Preferences: Java > Editor > Templates* use the following template:

```
private static final String LOG_CATEGORY_TYPE = ${enclosing_type}.class.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

As well you can try to use Lombok with annotation for logs.

https://projectlombok.org/features/log

https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/java/Log.html
https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/slf4j/Slf4j.html